# Set indent on view in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, indentation, zend-layout

In Zend Framework, it is possible to set indentation for headMeta(), headLink(), etc:

```
<?= $this->headLink()->setIndent("\t\t") ?>
```

I like this. I like things tidy. So, now I would want to indent my entire view as well in the *layout.phtml* file, causing every new line in the view script to be indented with X tabs.

```
<?= $this->layout()->setIndent("\t\t")->content ?>
```

This does not work. Is there any way to do this within Zend Framework without having to intercept the output with ob_start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_Layout has no `setIndent()`, check here: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_Layout.html#Zend_Layout You have to take care of the indentation by yourself in your template.

A generic solution would be to use [**Tidy** with Zend Framework](http://www.lautr.com/zend-framework-tidy-html-view-helper). The options to use then would be

```
indent => true
indent-spaces => 4
```

Comment: 'No' is certainly an answer to my question. Thanks for the help and the tip to use Tidy! I will give it a try.